# Тo main manifest attribute при сборке через maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

Решил собрать jar через maven.
pom.xml:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>7</source>
                <target>7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/stax/stax-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>stax</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

При сборке почему-то выдаёт ошибку:

```
no main manifest attribute, in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Personal Projects\XMLReadre\target\xmlReader-1.0.jar
```

Структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и, т.к. у меня в jar файле необходимо будет указать 2 аргумента вызов будет выглядеть следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.company.Main</mainClass>//папка.имя твоего класса
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/stax/stax-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>stax</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

потом просто install :  JAR будет в папке target

Comment: Теперь выкидывает ошибку о том, что не хватает библиотек, которые указаны в зависимостях

Comment: @i_burykin autoimport включен для mavena? и еше посмотри в dependencies там есть эти самые библиотеки и у себя в проекте тоже

Comment: да, autoimport для мавена включен. ругается на `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson` а в зависимостх можно посмотреть в maven'е он у меня подключен

Comment: @i_burykin версию смени gson попробуй снова

Comment: попробовал 3 разичные версии gson'a все равно не хочет(

Comment: @i_burykin если и это не поможет я пас но нашет как создать jar с мавеном все верно : у тебя случаем в пакете нет схожого jara? selenium-java-2.53.0 если есть удали и обнови проект

Comment: неа, нет такого(

Comment: @i_burykin выдели ошибку в отдельный вопрос + поищи в google